# java parse tweet corpus json

Tags: java, json, twitter

I have a problem: I need to parse a JSON file in Java where each line represents a tweet and follows the standard JSON of Twitter. I do not need all the information, I attach two photos to show you which fields I need. I would do it without using any support library. Thank you!

This is what I did for now. I do not think it's the best way to do it, especially going ahead I'll be in trouble because the names of many fields repeat

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class TweetCorpus implements Iterable<Tweet>
{
    private List<Tweet> tweets;

    public static TweetCorpus parseFile(File file)
    {
        List<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<>();

        try(BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(file.toPath()))
        {
            while(br.ready())
            {
                String tweet = br.readLine();
                //System.out.println(tweet);
                if(!tweet.isEmpty())
                {
                    long l = Long.parseLong(tweet.substring(tweet.indexOf("\"id\":") + 5, tweet.indexOf(",\"id_str\":")));
                    String t = tweet.substring(tweet.indexOf(",\"text\":\"") + 9, tweet.indexOf(",\"source\":"));
                    tweets.add(new Tweet(l, t));
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new TweetCorpus(tweets);
    }

    public int getTweetCount() { return tweets.size(); }

    public TweetCorpus(List<Tweet> tweets)
    {
        this.tweets = tweets;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Tweet> iterator()
    {
        return tweets.iterator();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TweetCorpus t = parseFile(new File("C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\Moroder\\Uni\\1 Anno - 2 Semestre\\Metodologie Di Programmazione\\Progetto\\HM4Test\\tweetsCorpus.js"));
        t.getTweetCount();

    }
}
```

**json media/retweet tweet**
[image: json media/retweet tweet]

**json "normal" tweet**
[image: json "normal" tweet]

Answer (score 0):

Re-inventing a JSON parser using only `readLine()` is a really bad idea. If you don't have experience writing parsers by hand, you will end up with a lot of bad code that is really hard to understand. Just use a library. There are tons of good JSON libraries for Java.

- [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind)
- [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)
- [Boon](https://github.com/boonproject/boon)

Example code:

```
static class User {
    String id, name;
}
static class MyTweet {
    String id, text;
    User user;
}
// if the entire file is a JSON array:
void parse(Reader r) {
    List<MyTweet> tweets = objectMapper.readValue(
        r, new TypeReference<List<MyTweet>>(){});
}
// if each line is a single JSON object:
void parse(BufferedReader r) {
    while (r.ready()) {
        String line = r.readLine();
        MyTweet tweet = objectMapper.readValue(line, MyTweet.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) java library to parse json to Tweet object. Their are tools online which generates pojo from json, which you can use with jackson to parse your json string to object.

Once you have json values in an object, you can use getters/setters to extract/modify the values you are interested in from input json.

Well writing your own parser would be a reinventing the wheel kind of task. But if your need is to write your own parser, refer to jackson project on github for inspiration on design and maintenance. 
This would help you in making a generic application.

Quick reference for jackson parser ,
https://dzone.com/articles/processing-json-with-jackson